# How do I get the index of an item inside of a ForEach loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, foreach, swiftui

I have an array of arrays that I'm looping through. The array is structured to represent the 4 quarters of a year:

Q0 January, February, March
Q1 April, May, June
Q2 July, August, September
Q3 October, November December

```
@State var quarters: [[Month]] = [[.init(name: "January"),.init(name: "February"),.init(name: "March")],
                               [.init(name: "April"), .init(name: "May"), .init(name: "June")],
                               [.init(name: "July"),.init(name: "August"),.init(name: "September")],
                               [.init(name: "October"), .init(name: "November"), .init(name: "December")]]
```

In the HStack below, I'm trying to append the index of `quarter` so that I end up with Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3

```
VStack {

    ForEach (self.quarters, id: \.self) { quarter in
        VStack {
        Spacer()
            HStack {

                Text("Q\(quarter.index)")
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .black, design: .rounded))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work. Is there a way I can get the index of the array inside the array of my ForEach loop here? I understand there is a way to retrieve the index if the ForEach loop is using a range as its data set, but I not if the data set is an array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this answer works because the data set of the ForEach loop is a range, not an array. It does not actually retrieve an index of an array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, but I need access to the objects inside of self.quarters, not just the range. If I used self.quarters.indices that would give me only a range, not access to the objects of self.quarters, am I right?

Comment: Oh, never mind my previous comments. I totally missed that you have an array of arrays. No wonder we are talking past each other. Sorry.

Comment: I am still not really shore what you want to do, is it to output Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 for each sub-array in the `quarters` array or do you want to access something within the sub-array (that is a Month instance)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go this way with an enumerated array:

```
   struct TempView: View{

   @State var quarters: [[Month]] = [[.init(name: "January", products: ["1", "2"]),.init(name: "February", products: ["1", "2"]),.init(name: "March", products: ["1", "2"])],
[.init(name: "April", products: ["1", "2"]), .init(name: "May", products: ["1", "2"]), .init(name: "June", products: ["1", "2"])]]

  var body: some View {

        ForEach (self.quarters.indices , id: \.self) { (index) in

        VStack {
        Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Q\(index)")
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .black, design: .rounded))
                Button("TestButton",action: {
                    self.quarters.append([.init(name: "January", products: ["1", "2"]),.init(name: "February", products: ["1", "2"]),.init(name: "March", products: ["1", "2"])])
                })
            }
             Spacer()
        }
    }

 }}
```

Comment: This mostly works, but I end up with 4 iterations of Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3 instead of 1.

Comment: I am trying to represent 4 quarters of the year. Q0 = [January, February, March] Q1 = [April, May, June] Q2 = [July, August, September] Q3 = [October, November, December]

Comment: in `self.quarters`, it should be 4 like = [[],[],[],[]]. So you will get 4 quarters. But in current data: there is only two = [[],.[] ], so you will only see two quarters. Just add more arrays to make it 4. What you see is depended on the data you provided, not the UI.

Comment: please see edit. The code before I edited was just for proof of concept. My update represents the proper data set, but I'm having the same issue as I mentioned.

Comment: It seems that your answer produces the right result for me if the second ForEach loop is removed :)

Comment: Mybad, I want to say both `ForEach` works. They are OR not AND relationships.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to look up the elements position in the array

```
Text("Q\(self.quarters.firstIndex(of: quarter)!)")
```